# PHPExcel load excel template from database blob without temporary file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there a way to load Excel template to PHPExcel from database blob without creating temporary file?

Comment: Simple answer, "No".... you might be able to use `php://temp` as the temporary file, though I've never tried it

Comment: Tried php://temp but unsuccessful. Mark, can you answer question with "No"?